# Can I set up a Mac for a multi head / multi user environment?

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, multiple-users

Using Linux you can connect multiple keyboards, monitors etc. and use one CPU with multiple users, each logged in to their own home environment.

See what I mean here: [Linuxgazette](http://linuxgazette.net/124/smith.html)

Is there any way to achieve the same on OS X?

Clarification:
All viewers seem to understand this question as: remote logon, or remote X. 
This is NOT the question.

I hope the following diagram will clarify:

```
|-------|
|single |
|MAC OS |
|box    |
|-------|
  |_Monitor1__keyb1__Mouse1__user1
  |
  |
  |_Monitor2__keyb2__Mouse2__user2
```

Remark:
It seems X11 is available on OS X. I haven't seen any practical examples yet. Remote X seems possible using X11. Not sure at all about multiseat capability with additional mouse and keyb..

Perhaps this may be 'a' way to go?

Comment: Something like this? http://9to5mac.com/2011/02/27/10-7-lion-allows-multi-user-remote-computing/

Comment: Of course, that's what UNIX was actually used for.

Comment: @slhck Thanks, but I already found this article. This method uses remot logon, so in fact you still have 2 machines running, whereas the other method uses only 1 cpu/machine.

Comment: @m0skit0 I'm aware of that too, but can you tell me how to do it?
You should be having multiple X-servers if I'm not mistaken, and change your X-config. I'm familiar with this on Linux but not on Mac, hence my question..

Comment: I think it might have been possible in really really old versions or OS X's predecessors. Maybe here's something better suited? http://www.aquaconnect.net/mac-terminal-server.php – also see: [Mac OS X multi-user thin client server (terminal server)?](http://serverfault.com/questions/8966/mac-os-x-multi-user-thin-client-server-terminal-server)

Comment: An alternative method is to run a virtual machine full screen and connect a pair of USB keyboard and mouse to the VM. The VM can run whatever OS you want or as a thin client to connect back to the host via VNC.

Answer (score 1):

Mac doesn't use X11 for its GUI so this setup is not possible with a mac.  You could try installing linux on your mac and trying this out but by the looks of the setup it would have to be a mac pro due to the multiple graphics cards.