# Single Mac hardware for multiple virtual Macs

Tags: macos, mac, multiple-monitors, virtual-machine, multiple-users

Is it possible to use a single mac for multiple users as if they were working on their own mac?

So would it be possible to connect for example two screens, two keyboards (bluetooth or not) and two mouses (bluetooth or not) and both be working like you have your own Mac? If it's not possible with macOS, is it possible by using virtual machine software and run two separate macOS installations? Is there a limit on how many users? Could you change the number of "virtual machines" or users easily?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I set up a Mac for a multi head / multi user environment?](http://superuser.com/questions/351549/can-i-set-up-a-mac-for-a-multi-head-multi-user-environment) and [Can a Mac be used by multiple users at same time?](http://superuser.com/questions/125636/can-a-mac-be-used-by-multiple-users-at-same-time)

Comment: Kind of a dupe, but the answer is much simpler these days.

Comment: & I just realised I read it completely wrongly... one mac, many simultaneous users... all local :/

Answer (score 0):

If your considering just 2 users, you could get pretty close to doing that by using VMWare Fusion. Connect keyboard/display/whatever else you want and tell that to be used by the virtual machine, and do the opposite for the mac itself.

Comment: Wouldn't this approach work for multiple users as well? I can run multiple virtual machines in VMWare Fusion at the same time no? I assume Parallels can do this too? I'm just worried about the performance of the two virtual machines... It would be faster if you could run two virtual machines on top of a lower OS no?